# Ubuntu OS:: Strongswan compilation is failing (make is failing)

Tags: compiling, make

I am using Ubuntu OS 22.04.
I have run "apt-get install strongswan"

- After I install "apt-get install opensc"
- After I install "apt-get install libgmp-dev"
- After I install "apt-get install libssl-dev"
- After I install "apt-get install libssh-dev"

Then

```
wget https://download.strongswan.org/strongswan-5.9.11.tar.gz
tar -xzf  strongswan-5.9.11.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/usr/local  --enable-openssl --sysconfdir=/etc
```

All the above commands ran successfully.

But when I run "make" command next, it ran for a while and threw a error message which I am finding it hard to get by. Pasting the snippet of the last ending make file logs. Appreciate if anybody could help as how to get through this.

```
root@arjun:/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11#make
.....................................
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/src/xfrmi'
depbase=`echo xfrmi.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I../../src/libstrongswan -I../../src/libcharon -I../../src/libcharon/plugins/kernel_netlink   -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unused-parameter -g -O2 -include /usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/config.h -MT xfrmi.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o xfrmi.o xfrmi.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unused-parameter -g -O2 -include /usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/config.h   -o xfrmi xfrmi.o ../../src/libcharon/plugins/kernel_netlink/libstrongswan-kernel-netlink.la ../../src/libstrongswan/libstrongswan.la ../../src/libcharon/libcharon.la

*** Warning: Linking the executable xfrmi against the loadable module
*** libstrongswan-kernel-netlink.so is not portable!
libtool: link: gcc -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unused-parameter -g -O2 -include /usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/config.h -o .libs/xfrmi xfrmi.o  ../../src/libcharon/plugins/kernel_netlink/.libs/libstrongswan-kernel-netlink.so ../../src/libstrongswan/.libs/libstrongswan.so ../../src/libcharon/.libs/libcharon.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/ipsec/plugins -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/ipsec
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/src/xfrmi'
Making all in starter
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/src/starter'
\
         -m 10 -C -G -D -t \
                --output-file=keywords.c ./keywords.txt
/bin/bash: line 2: -m: command not found
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1046: keywords.c] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/src/starter'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:539: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:604: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11'
make: *** [Makefile:515: all] Error 2
root@eksa-cp01:/usr/src/strongswan-5.9.11#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to build `strongswan` - when you have already installed it from the repository? The error seems to be because `make` is trying to build `src/starter/keywords.c` despite your system missing `gperf` - however `keywords.c` in the tarball should be up to date and not need to be rebuilt.